# How to show that a formula is not a norm in function space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I have to show that the formula $||g|| = |g(c)|, c \in [a, b]$ ($c$ is fixed) does not define a norm in the space $\mathcal{C}([a, b]$) of continuous functions on the interval $[a, b]$. I find proofs in vector spaces easy, as then the formulas are usually defined in terms of the components of the vectors. But I do not know how to make the jump to function spaces.

Namely here, it is pretty obvious that unless we have a zero constant function, $||g|| \neq 0$. Also the scalar multiplication seem pretty obvious, as for $t \in [a, b]$ we have that $||t\cdot g|| = |tg(c)| = |t||g(c)|$. So the only thing left would be to show that somehow the triangle inequality does not hold with this formula. But expanding $||g + f|| = |(g + f)(c)| = |g(c) + f(c)| \leq |g(c)| + |f(c)|$. So where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g$ is not the zero function, but $g(c)=0$, then we have $||g||=0$.

If we asumme that $|| \cdot||$ defines a norm, then we would obtain $g=0,$ a contradiction.